# Using HtmlUnit to get the access token from instagram

Tags: java, instagram, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

Since httpURLconnection didn't cut out, i switched to htmlUnit to get programatically the auth code to get the access token from instagram and then do whatever i need from there, the thing is i'm stuck trying to retrieve the authorization code from the url

> mysite.com/?code=ca1ec5b06a0b409293cff74ed9876a46

but i can't access to that link since it doesn't seems to be redirected from the authorization URL. this one:

> https://instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login=&next=/oauth/authorize/%3Fclient_id%CLIENT_ID%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%3A//MYSITE.COM%26response_type%3Dcode

this is my code where i try to access to that url:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);     
    HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(authURL);
    WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse();
    String content = response.getContentAsString();
    System.out.println(page.getUrl());
```

Comment: You need to isolate the root cause, please fully read http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by trying to get the authorization url without being logged to the site, then when i was asked to login, i used [htmlunit to get the html form to login to instagram](http://harisupriyanto.blogspot.mx/2013/10/using-htmlunit-for-login.html), finally i could get the desired redirect url with the code.